# Unable to migrate Custom Metadata settings using ANT in salesforce

Tags: ant, custom-metadata

I was looking to Migrate the Custom Metadata settings from Dev to SIT box. For that I created the following package.xml. I have total 5 different custom metada setting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomMetadata</name>
    </types>
    <version>40.0</version>
</Package>
```

Using `retrieveUnpackaged` command, able to fetch all the Custom Metadata settings and trying to deploy all these components to SIT using `deployUnpackaged` command. Note: Commands used as per `build.xml` file.

But unable to deploy those packages, because I feel through ANT deployment there is no way to create Custom Metadata schema first then deploy all the records. Any guidance on how to create Custom medata schema using ANT or how to migrate newly Custom Metadata settings to target org ?

Comment: Jitendra Zaa has an [introduction](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/how-to-retrieve-and-deploy-custom-metadata-types-using-ant/) to Custom Metadata in package.xml. I was mistaken about this myself - the IDEs handle it a little differently.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I got the solution from the link : http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/tag/ant-migration-tool/ . Custom Metadata is also an Object. You just need to fetch the details like any other `Custom object` then above `package.xml` will load all records into the `Custom Metadata`.

This is working very fine for me.

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>ABC__mdt</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>40.0</version>
</Package>
```